# Subscribe to Azure IoT Hub Device Events

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I want to read the "Microsoft.Devices.DeviceConnected" events (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid#event-types) from Azure IoT Hub. The only examples I found deals with Azure Event Grid but I'd rather like to use the IoT Hub's internal endpoint (Event Hub). Is this even possible?
When I subscribe to the internal Event Hub using the *EventProcessorHost* interface all I get are D2C user telemetry messages.

Comment: You can't, unless you somehow send a custom made event your self from the device.

Answer (score 1):

Like @PeterBons said, this feature is not supported by Azure IoT Hub, however can be done outside of the Azure IoT Hub using an Azure Function. The following screen snippet shows this integration where the EventGrid events are pushed to the IoT Hub Stream:

[image]

As you can see, the above *EventGridTrigger* function is an **integrator** between the Azure Event Grid and Azure IoT Hub. This integrator has a responsibility to consume an event grid events, mapping to the D2C Message and send it to the Azure IoT Hub as a virtual IoT device (backend device) with a Https protocol.

**Update:**

The following code snippet is an example of the Azure Function - Integrator to the Azure IoT Hub:

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models;


// reusable client proxy
static HttpClientHelper iothub = new HttpClientHelper(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureIoTHubShariedAccessPolicy"));

public static async Task Run(EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());

    // my virtual backend iot device
    string deviceId = "Device13";
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventGridEvent), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    await iothub.Client.PostAsync($"/devices/{deviceId}/messages/events?api-version=2018-06-30", content);
}




// helpers
class HttpClientHelper
{
    HttpClient client;
    DateTime expiringSaS;
    (string hostname, string keyname, string key) config;

    public HttpClientHelper(string connectionString)
    {
        config = GetPartsFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://{config.hostname}")};
        SetAuthorizationHeader();         
    }

    public HttpClient Client
    {
        get
        {          
            if (expiringSaS < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
            {
               SetAuthorizationHeader();  
            }         
            return client;
        }
    }

    internal void SetAuthorizationHeader()
    {
        lock (client)
        {
            if (expiringSaS < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1)) 
            {
                string sasToken = GetSASToken(config.hostname, config.key, config.keyname, 1);
                if (client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", sasToken);
                expiringSaS = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
            }
        }
    }

    internal (string hostname, string keyname, string key) GetPartsFromConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        var parts = connectionString.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2)).ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());
        return (parts["HostName"] ?? "", parts["SharedAccessKeyName"] ?? "", parts["SharedAccessKey"] ?? "");
    }

    internal string GetSASToken(string resourceUri, string key, string keyName = null, uint hours = 24)
    {
        var expiry = GetExpiry(hours);
        string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(key));

        var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
        var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, $"SharedAccessSignature sr={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri)}&sig={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature)}&se={expiry}");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyName))
            sasToken += $"&skn={keyName}";
        return sasToken;
    }

    internal string GetExpiry(uint hours = 24)
    {
        TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        return Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + 3600 * hours);
    }
}
```

and function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "eventGridEvent",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: OK, thank you so far. So to clear things up: I need an Event Subscription in the first place to process the events from the device. There is no other solution to act on those events right? What I managed so far is using the global Event Grid resource (Event Subscriptions) and hooking it up to a Storage Queue which also seems like a nice solution. If you say "virtual IoT device" does this somehow map to those device already being registered in the IoT Hub or would it create a second device or how would this work?

Comment: First of all, the source of the interest (events) such as device connected/disconnected, device registered/deleted is an Azure IoT Hub, not the device. In the above solution, the Event Subscription for that event types and topic is hooked to the EventGridTrigger function. The "virtual IoT device" is basically your backend device (in my example name is Device13) and must be in prior registered manually or programmatically. In the above example, the Device13 has been already registered. How to map the EventGrid event to the non-telemetry data is up to your requirements.

Comment: OK that makes sense to me. But using the Event Grid is the way to go or are there any altervatives like "message routing" which also seems to offer this capabilities?
And do you see any pros/cons if you compare your approach to mine where I just hook up a globally created event subscription to a Storage Queue? Maybe there is a big difference regarding the pricing... 
Also, do you know what the difference is in terms of using the global Event Subscription (Event Grid) or creating a new one? Is it OK for this scenario to just use the global one?

Comment: your event pattern is Push-Pull-Push, the above solution is Push-Push, that is the major difference between them. There is no built-in message routing for that kind of source interest such as device connected, … in the Azure IoT Hub. Alternative solution for this event types can be used a feature  Diagnostic settings Log/Metrics and streaming to the separate Event Hub

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! *virtual hug*

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that you quite easily can create an event subscription (using Event Grid) under Events in the IoT Hub and push Connection events (e.g. Device Connected or Device Disconnected) to an Azure Function, Event Hub or Service Bus etc.

Answer (score 0):

An IoT hub has a default built-in-endpoint (messages/events) that is compatible with Event Hubs. You can create custom endpoints to route messages to by linking other services in your subscription to the IoT Hub.

[image]

Here is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#routing-endpoints) to the relevant Azure documentation